# Does float:left make many <div>s/<p>s stay in a single line?

Tags: html, css, css-float, inline

I have 5 menu buttons to be displayed in a line one after the other.

I put `float:left` in the style of the button's class.

That did the job for me.

Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_inline).
If I change `display:inline` to `float:left`, it doesn't line up the 2 paragraphs.
*Which is the right approach to this?*

EDIT:I found that it works fine in JS Fiddle but not on w3schools. So that creates some confusion.

Comment: For live HTML/CSS demos can I suggest: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: Is this one on w3schools inaccurate?

Comment: what is your problem? i dont understand ..

Comment: Yes,I notice it works on JS Fiddle.

Comment: Problem is it didn't work on w3schools. I found this demo there and edited it.

Comment: try display:inline-block

Comment: Note that, by default, JSFiddle normalizes the CSS. This my be the reason you see different outputs from w3cshools and JSFiddle...

Comment: Sigh. W3schools samples never use a doctype, so you get quirks mode in browsers. Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the start of the sample HTML and the lines will line up neatly. Better still, [don't use w3schools at all](http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div { white-space: nowrap }
p { display: inline }
```

This will keep the paragraphs allways side by side. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gxh46/)

If you need to set the paragraphs to display: inline-block, be shure to change these elements to elements that are inline-elements by default, to get it work in older IEs.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand you're last sentence. Would you clarify that?

Comment: What i mean is: This example works with every HTML element as long as you use `display: inline` for the elements (in this case p-elements), that you wanna have always side by side. If you want to use `display: inline-block` for these elements, then i recommend you to not use a block-elements, to get it work in older Internet Explorer versions, use inline-elements instead. [more about inline-/block-elements](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/). `display: inline-block` enables you to set widths to the elements. Hope it's more clearly now.

Comment: inline-elements fits the width of the content inside, while block-elements take automatically the available width of the parent element by default.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use either one. I'd personally choose floating elements for your button layout.

Answer to your topics question is yes, they will stay on same line IF the sum of widths of div-tags and p-tags are not greater than the surrounding elements width.

For example:

```
//HTML
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="button">buttoncontent</div>
    <div class="button">buttoncontent</div>
</div>  

//CSS
.wrapper {
    width: 100px;
}

.button {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
}
```

In the example the second button will print on its own line because the total width of buttons is 120px and the surrounding elements width is only 100px. If the width for class button would be 40px then the two button elements would print on same line.

Comment: This information is incorrect. Divs *AND* P tags display as block level elements by default. The one thing that differs them is that P tags will normally have a top/bottom margin applied by default where as Divs will not. http://jsfiddle.net/Db4Xf/